# Retrieve country code from RDF source recieved via Sparql query

Tags: sparql, rdf, semantic-web

I have the following query on this endpoint https://data.bnf.fr/sparql/ :

```
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdagroup2elements: <http://rdvocab.info/ElementsGr2/>
PREFIX bio: <http://vocab.org/bio/0.1/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
SELECT distinct ?name ?nationality
WHERE {
?oeuvre dcterms:creator ?author.
?author foaf:name ?name.
?author rdagroup2elements:countryAssociatedWithThePerson ?nationality.
}
ORDER BY DESC (?mort) LIMIT 100
```

Which returns a list of authors with a nationality field that is itself another RDF source :
[image]

So, for the first author Jean Martin, I get this link to another RDF source, in the case for the country France : http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/countries/fr

How could I modify the query to receive the country code (or country name, if not possible) instead of this link, in this case FR (or France)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An alternative to extracting the country code from the URI, using "the Linked Data way":

The default graph of the endpoint https://data.bnf.fr/sparql/ doesn’t provide any data about the entities under the namespace `http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/countries/`, but it provides entities under the namespace `http://data.bnf.fr/vocabulary/countrycodes/`, which have an `owl:sameAs` link to them.

For example:

```
<http://data.bnf.fr/vocabulary/countrycodes/fr> <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#sameAs> <http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/countries/fr> .
```

And these `http://data.bnf.fr/vocabulary/countrycodes/` entities refer to the country code with `skos:notation`, and to the country name with `skos:prefLabel` (language-tagged).

For these cases, getting the country code would be possible with this property path:

```
?author rdagroup2elements:countryAssociatedWithThePerson/^owl:sameAs/skos:notation ?countryCode .
```

Unfortunately, only some `rdagroup2elements:countryAssociatedWithThePerson` values are under the `http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/countries/` namespace, while other values are under the `http://data.bnf.fr/vocabulary/countrycodes/` namespace directly.

To find both cases, you could use `UNION`:

```
{ ?author rdagroup2elements:countryAssociatedWithThePerson/^owl:sameAs/skos:notation ?countryCode . } 
UNION 
{ ?author rdagroup2elements:countryAssociatedWithThePerson/skos:notation ?countryCode . }
```

The full query:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX owl: <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdagroup2elements: <http://rdvocab.info/ElementsGr2/>
PREFIX bio: <http://vocab.org/bio/0.1/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>
    
SELECT DISTINCT ?name ?countryCode
WHERE {
  ?oeuvre dcterms:creator ?author.
  ?author foaf:name ?name.
  
  { ?author rdagroup2elements:countryAssociatedWithThePerson/^owl:sameAs/skos:notation ?countryCode . } 
  UNION 
  { ?author rdagroup2elements:countryAssociatedWithThePerson/skos:notation ?countryCode . }
  
}
LIMIT 100
```

(In case you didn’t intend it: Your query treats different persons with the same name and country as one entry. To prevent this, you could output the person’s URI.)

Comment: Thanks a lot for this alternative, very complete answer all the explanations, the whole picture is much more clear to me now. I was indeed confused with the two namespaces. Sorry for the noob question if the answer is obvious, how did you find out that entities under the namespace `http://data.bnf.fr/vocabulary/countrycodes/`, have an `owl:sameAs` link to them ?

Comment: @GuillaumeBihet: If you find an entity as value, you can make a quick query to check which properties and values exist: `SELECT * WHERE { <http://data.bnf.fr/vocabulary/countrycodes/fr> ?p ?o . }`. –– To find out more about entities for which no properties+values exist (like the LoC entities from your example), you can make another query to check how/if these are used as objects: `SELECT * WHERE { ?s ?p <http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/countries/fr> . }`. If there are many results, you might have to filter some out (e.g., remove `rdagroup2elements:countryAssociatedWithThePerson` from `?p`).

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot @Stefan - brox IT-Solutions

Comment: The `owl:sameAs` part can be replaced with `(^owl:sameAs|owl:sameAs)*` to allow an arbitrary number of relations (and be future-proof).

Answer (score 1):

You can use SPARQL [replace function](https://www.w3.org/TR/sparql11-query/#func-replace):

```
SELECT ... (REPLACE(STR(?nationality), "http://id.loc.gov/vocabulary/countries/", "") AS ?nationalityShort)
WHERE ...
```

to extract the code from the url.

But you can as well link to this resource and retrieve additional fields from it like `sos:notation` in your case:

```
PREFIX skos: <http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#>
PREFIX rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>
PREFIX rdagroup2elements: <http://rdvocab.info/ElementsGr2/>
PREFIX bio: <http://vocab.org/bio/0.1/>
PREFIX dcterms: <http://purl.org/dc/terms/>
PREFIX foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/>
PREFIX xsd: <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#>

SELECT distinct ?name ?nationalityCode
WHERE {
  ?oeuvre dcterms:creator ?author.
  ?author foaf:name ?name.
  ?author rdagroup2elements:countryAssociatedWithThePerson ?nationality.
  ?nationality skos:notation ?nationalityCode
}
ORDER BY DESC (?mort) LIMIT 100
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @krzystof Majewski, I was trying with `nationality rdfs:label ?country` and tried other things but completely new to it and didn't know `skos` yet.

Comment: You can always run query like `select * where { <http://data.bnf.fr/vocabulary/countrycodes/fr> ?predicate ?object }` to get a list of all properties and values of a given node